# Regex match chars not between 2 specific chars or words

Tags: regex

i'm trying to make this regex work but i only had an half-success.

So far i could make this work:

> match every ';' that is not between '[]'

with this regex: `;(?![^\[]*\])`

But now comes my problem... i should also add this limitation:

> match every ';' that is not between '[' and ']' or 'XXX' and 'ZZZ'

So for example in this text:

```
aaa **;** bbb **;** [ ccc *;* ddd ] eee **;** XXX qweasd *;* qwesad ZZZ
```

the third and last ';' should not match

Comment: @Thefourthbird No, but the third semicolon _is_ in between `[` and `]`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You are right, I missed one

Comment: Which programming language do you use here? `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` might be an option.

Comment: In most cases, you can do  it without the need of lookarounds. What is the programming language and what is the final result? Do you remove/replace/extract/count occurrences/split?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pattern seems to be working:

```
;(?![^[]*\])(?!((?!XXX).)*ZZZ)
```

Explanation:

```
;                   match a semicolon
(?![^[]*\])         assert that we cannot look forward and see a ] without also seeing
                    an opening [
                       -> this implies that the semicolon is not in between []
(?!((?!XXX).)*ZZZ)  assert that we cannot look forward and see ZZZ without
                    first seeing XXX
                       -> this implies that the semicolon is not in between XXX and ZZZ
```

### Demo

Note that this solution assumes that you would not have nested `[]` brackets anywhere, or nested XXX...ZZZ, but rather only single level.

Comment: @Mandy8055 Yes, I could do that, but IMHO it would make the pattern harder to read, and it's also not clear that there would be any performance gains in doing so.

Comment: @Mandy8055 No need to, the solution won't help since it [does not match](https://regex101.com/r/yP7hJd/1/) `;` even when it is not between `XXX` and `ZZZ` or `[` and `]`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `the solution won't help since` ... it _will_ help if the OP can state that brackets would always be balanced, and `XXX` would never appear without later matching `ZZZ`.

Comment: wow guys, your were super fast responding, i just did some tests and this seems to be working for me. It should all be on a single level with no nested []. 
ty very much.

Answer (score 1):

If `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` is an option (`PHP`, `PyPi Regex` the like), you might get along with

```
(?:\[[^][]+\]|XXX.+?ZZZ)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|;
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/JS76jN/1/).

---

Explanation:

```
(?:             # non-capturing parenthesis
    \[[^][]+\]  # anything between [ and ]
    |           # or
    XXX.+?ZZZ   # XXX ... ZZZ
)(*SKIP)(*FAIL) # all of this should be skipped
|               # ... or ...
;               # match a ;
```